# Warning: Unknown event handler property `onClick` in React.js web app

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs

This is the part of the code involved in the error.

```
const Balance = () => {
     async function onGetBalance() {
         const balance = await client.api.network.getBalance({ address: 'AcyLq3tokVpkMBMLALVMWRdVJ83TTgBUwU' });
         alert('onGetBalance: ' + JSON.stringify(balance));
              };
    
    return(
    <Button onClick={onGetBalance}></Button>
    )
    };
    export default Balance;
```

The `getbalance` function communicates with an API of an online banking app and alerts the account balance.

The original file is a Typescript file and it is this:

```
export const Network: React.SFC<RouterProps> = (props) => {

async function onGetBalance() {
    const balance = await client.api.network.getBalance({ address: 'AcyLq3tokVpkMBMLALVMWRdVJ83TTgBUwU' });
    alert('onGetBalance: ' + JSON.stringify(balance));
  }
return (
    <div>
      <button onClick={onGetNetwork}>getNetwork</button>
</div>
);
};
```

The original file works, I guess it depends on `props`.
I tried with:

```
const Balance = (props) => {...
```

but it does not work. Unfortunately the only examples of how to use the API are in Typescript and I am having some difficulties and have not found other solutions by googling.

Comment: You have a spelling mistake - `onCklic` should be `onClick`

Comment: Sorry, I misspelled only in the question. In the original file it is right.

Comment: Hi, which part is the one that doesn't work?

Comment: You misspelled it both in the component and the error message in the title?

Comment: Yes, copy and paste 'onCklic' from codeblock to title.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code looks correct(same as TypeScript file) but try `debugging` or `console` the value of `balance` to check if you are getting any value if you aren't than your `API code` has some problem and check that code.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. Apparently this error appears because of your IDE. When I wrote "onClick" myself, I got this error. But when I wrote "onC" and selected "onClick" in the tooltip menu, everything worked.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).